# MonoDevelop F# tooltips for type and function signatures; Do they Exist?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, tooltip, monodevelop, function-signature

Trying to work with MonoDevelop (F#) on Linux and it's quite painful without the tooltips(type/func signatures) im used to in VS. Is this functionality available in MonoDevelop? Assuming latest builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as per @SushiHangover advice was to build latest MonoDevelop from source. No additional addins were required to see F# tooltips. https://github.com/mono/monodevelop

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using MonoDevelop 6+ there is a FSharp Addin

[F# Editing Support In MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio](https://github.com/fsharp/xamarin-monodevelop-fsharp-addin/)

#### Features:

```
Code completion
Syntax highlighting
Tooltips
Debugging
Target .NET 3.5, 4.0, 4.5
F# Interactive scripting (Alt-Enter execution)
Templates (Console Application, Library, Tutorial Project, Gtk Project, iOS, Android)
Makefile support
Supports F# 3.0 type providers (requires F# 3.0)
xbuild support for Visual Studio .fsproj and .sln files without change (requires Mono 3.0 and F# 3.0)
```

#### Prerequisites

To use F# language support please ensure that you have F# installed on your system, for details on this please see http://fsharp.org

#### Installation

First check install MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio. Check if F# support is already installed using the AddIn manager. MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio --> Add-in manager --> Language Bindings --> Check for F# binding

If so, just use it, no installation is required.

If not, install the F# Language Binding via the AddIn manager.

MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio --> Add-in manager --> Gallery --> Language Bindings --> F# Language Binding

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as per the Mono page installation guide (Ubuntu apt-get route), I am running MonoDevelop 5.1 with F# Language Binding Addin 5.5 and infuriatingly I still don't have any tool tips over function signatures or value types in F#. Running on Lubuntu. It is clearly stated in the documentation that recent distributions should have tooltips. I will clone the most recent version and see if there is an improvement...

Comment: @RossBonallo I tend to avoid `apt-get` for Mono/MonoDevelop as the disto packages time lag is painful. Building MD is straight forward if you have  Mono MDK install and the basic auto tools installed. Currently I'm building MonoDevelop from source and thus am using version 6.2 (171) and F# Binding v6.2 and it is working fine.

Comment: Built the lastest version of MonoDevelop which does infact have tooltips. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I'm up and running but the addIns for 6.2 don't work, repo not found, how did you get past this? I'm looking to get the vim addIn installed, I've tried building the plugin from source but I can't compile the solution...